# How to create ADT in Haskell?

Tags: scala, haskell, algebraic-data-types

In Scala I can describe such ADT:

```scala
sealed trait Foo
case class A(a: Int) extends Foo
case class B(b: String) extends Foo
case class C(a: A, b: B) extends Foo
```

How can I do the same in Haskell?

```
data Foo = A Int | B String | C A B
```

It doesn't work, because A and B are not types. Should I use GHC extensions to do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Scala, your ADT makes `A`,`B`,`C` to be subtypes of `Foo`. In Haskell we do not have subtypes, so `A`,`B`,`C` are instead constructors of type `Foo`.

A few possible workarounds:

1. Repeat the fields. This is the most basic option.

   ```hs
   data Foo = A Int | B String | C Int String
   ```
2. Define additional types, so that we can reuse them more than once.

   ```hs
   data AT = AT Int      -- can have many arguments
   data BT = BT String   -- can have many arguments
   data Foo = A AT | B BT | C AT BT
   ```
3. Exploit a GADT

   ```hs
   data FooTag = AT | BT | CT

   data Foo (tag :: FooTag) where
      A :: Int -> Foo 'AT
      B :: String -> Foo 'BT
      C :: Foo 'AT -> Foo 'BT -> Foo 'CT
   ```

   Here, in the last line we are able to refer to "the values constructed using `A`"   using the type `Foo 'AT`, since tag `AT` is only used by constructor `A`.
   Note that this approach adds a tag parameter to `Foo`, so it slightly changes the interface: we can no longer write `bar :: Foo -> ...`, but we have to write `bar :: Foo t -> ...` (or to use existential types).

Comment: The last example requires several extensions, though, right? (`DataKinds`, `GADTs`, and `KindSignatures`, I think.)